# how to display tabular data in angularjs with angular-material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

As for now, angular material does not offer any table directive or similar, what might be the best way to display any tabular data? I've already discovered [this lib](https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table) but maybe there is an easier way?!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Material Design Lite and just use the table component. It's very straight forward to integrate with Angular.

[Google Material Design Lite Tables](https://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#tables-section)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use this:

`mdDataTable`: https://github.com/iamisti/mdDataTable

install with:

`npm install mdDataTable` or `bower install mdDataTable`

demo page for it: http://iamisti.github.io/mdDataTable/